# Ruby abstract database connector

Tags: ruby, activerecord, database-connection

I'm writing a Ruby gem that requires to make a very simple query to an unknown database among the next: sqlite, mysql, postgresql.

For now I'm using *ActiveRecord* to handle this idiosyncrasy but looks like a bit overwhelming for me since I'm not using 99% of the *ActiveRecord* power.

I need something to play with in the next way:

```
connection = AbstractConnection.new("adapter", "database" {, "username", "userpass"})
connection.query("select * from table")
```

Is there any gem that abstracts me of generating the connection to different adapters? Is it using *ActiveRecord* a good idea here?

Comment: Since the database can be any kind "select * from table" won't be valid in all databases. Well it is valid in sqlite, mysql and postgresql but not in others. It feels that you want abstraction for the connection but not for the query. And it seems strange to me because queries can vary a lot depending on the database… I don't know if it is a good idea to have an abstract connection without abstract queries

Comment: You are right @AurélienBottazini let's narrow the _any_ to the 3 adapters in the description.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use ActiveRecord, you could use:

1. [Sqlite3 gem](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby)
2. [MongoDB driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/ruby-driver-tutorial/)
3. [Pg gem](https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/wiki/Home)
4. [MySQL driver for Ruby](https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/)

ActiveRecord provides a much nicer DSL across databases, but if you don't need all the overhead then you might want to invest some time in picking up one of the above.

If, however, you think that you may want to change database type in the future, then I recommend you use ActiveRecord: your code will stay the same and the underlying framework will deal with the changed database type.

Hope this helps!